# Access a Windows XP tablet share from another subnet

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, ip

I have a Windows XP tablet that is connected to my computer via an IP address that I can access files from my computer (Windows 7) with no problems. My computer is also on a network and if I want to access the tablets files from another computer(Windows 7) I would need to go through my computer.
[image]

Any simple options for this?

Comment: Do you have a firewall between your router and your PCs?  I assume your tablet uses wireless access?

Comment: Firewalls are off and I have connected it via cable.

Comment: I would get a hardware firewall and create routes for all subnets. ex.: 192.x.x.x to 10.x.x.x

Comment: Can you provide us with information on IP addressing you are using in those two subnets? What are IP addresses of Tablet1, Computer1 interface connecting to Tablet1, Computer1 interface connecting to the Router? Did you enable routing on Computer 1?